# Can not find Aasiaat, Greenland in HERE autosuggest endpoint

Tags: here-api

I can not find the town Aasiaat in Greenland with the autosuggest endpoint of the HERE API.

I can find it on Here we go:
 [https://wego.here.com/*/*/city-town-village/aasiaat--loc-dmVyc2lvbj0xO3RpdGxlPU42OC43MDk3MislMkMrVzUyLjg2OTQ0O2xhdD02OC43MDk3Mjtsb249LTUyLjg2OTQ0O2NhdGVnb3J5SWQ9Y2l0eS10b3duLXZpbGxhZ2U7c291cmNlU3lzdGVtPWludGVybmFs?map=68.70972,-52.86944,15,normal&msg=Aasiaat&x=ep](https://wego.here.com/_/_/city-town-village/aasiaat--loc-dmVyc2lvbj0xO3RpdGxlPU42OC43MDk3MislMkMrVzUyLjg2OTQ0O2xhdD02OC43MDk3Mjtsb249LTUyLjg2OTQ0O2NhdGVnb3J5SWQ9Y2l0eS10b3duLXZpbGxhZ2U7c291cmNlU3lzdGVtPWludGVybmFs?map=68.70972,-52.86944,15,normal&msg=Aasiaat&x=ep)

but not with the autosuggest endpoint:

```
curl \
  --compressed \
  -H 'Accept-Encoding:gzip' \
  -H 'Accept-Language:en-US,de;q=0.7,en;q=0.3' \
  -H 'Geolocation:geo:64.1941,-49.5643' \
  --get 'https://places.demo.api.here.com/places/v1/autosuggest' \
    --data-urlencode 'app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg' \
    --data-urlencode 'app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL' \
    --data-urlencode 'pretty=true' \
    --data-urlencode 'q=Aasiaat'
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Please clear what have you tried and what should the expected answer be. The link you provided is giving 403

Comment: strange the link works for me. but if you search for Aasiaat on wego.here.com you will get a result. If you search with the autosuggest endpoint of the HERE Places API, the town Aasiaat is not in the results. My Question is why. Do i need to change the settings? Because the data seems to be available in the HERE database

Comment: Its blocked in my country

Answer (score 0):

Currently the Greenland isn't coverage by Places API.

Country Support

[The table lists](https://developer.here.com/documentation/places/dev_guide/topics/coverage-information.html) the level of Search support for each country, either Full, Intermediate, or Entry. In this table doesn't exist at this moment the country Greenland apologies for it.

Coverage Information

When you use the Places (Search) API to build an application, your users can find individual locations in:

over 200 countries
over 1.5 million different areas (cities, districts, regions)
over 25 million streets split into 90 million and more individual segments
In an increasing number of countries, the Places (Search) API provides detailed, building-specific location information (over 120 million point addresses within 15 countries).

Places (Search) API offers information about over 63 million named and categorized places in 239 countries:

- over 10 countries with more than 1 million places over 53 countries
- with more than 100 thousand places